# Change title attribute of dynamically generated html element for tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, tooltip

I have a dynamically generated HTML element that includes a title attribute which appears in a tooltip when hovering, like:

```
<div title="tooltip text" class="classname" id="identifier"></div>
```

I would like to change the contents of the title attribute using javascript code set to run as part of the HTML render. Currently, my code is as follows:

```
var changeTooltip = function(){
     var TooltipElement = document.getElementsByClassName("classname");
     if (TooltipElement.title = "tooltip text"){
         TooltipElement.title = "new message";
     };
};

window.onload = changeTooltip();
```

This code leaves the original string in the div's title attribute once the page renders fully. Can anyone explain why, and possibly show the correct way? Note that I must use JS, I cannot use JQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName()` (note the plural *Elements*) returns a *list* of elements. Loop through that:

```js
var changeTooltip = function(){
  var TooltipElements = document.getElementsByClassName("classname");
  
  for ( var i = 0; i < TooltipElements.length; ++i )
  {
    var TooltipElement = TooltipElements[i];
      
    if (TooltipElement.title == "tooltip text")
      TooltipElement.title = "new message";
  };
};

changeTooltip();
```

```css
.classname:after {
  content: attr(title);
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div title="tooltip text" class="classname" id="identifier">Title: </div>
<div title="other text" class="classname" id="identifier2">Title: </div>
```

Finally, you need to change:

```
window.onload = changeTooltip();
```

to

```
window.onload = changeTooltip;
```

so that the function doesn't run until everything is loaded.

Comment: This doesn't throw any errors, but still does not achieve the desired result for me. The original title attribute remains.

Comment: Then we'd need to see the *actual* HTML and javascript, names and all, involved. As you can see, it works fine in the example here. Are there any errors in the [JavaScript console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)?

Comment: What happens when you fix the `onload` assignment, per my edited answer?

Comment: I really can't provide that since I'm trying to customize a piece of software for my company. When I try running the following code, I get the expected result in the dialog box that appears, but it doesn't hold once the page fully loads: `var changePersonalTooltip = function(){
 var personalElement = document.getElementsByClassName("iwov-icon iwov-img-personaldisable");
 if (personalElement.title = "Show personalization results"){
  personalElement.title = "test";
  alert(personalElement.title);
  alert("Function ended.");
 }else{
  alert("Function failed.");
 };
};`

Comment: Note that the code you pasted still has the "trying to give a title to a list of elements" bug. Still wondering what happens when you repair the `onload` assignment.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but it seems to get me further than looping through the array, which throws a `null object` error. Also, the `onload` assignment didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Bad code that doesn't throw an error is still bad code. And the fixed *sample* code doesn't throw an error, but we can't see the *real* code/HTML, so I'm kind of at a loss.

Comment: Can you think of any reason why trying to identify the element using getElementById would throw a `null object`? Would a dynamically generated element need to be identified some other way?

Comment: `getElementById()` is from the other answer. It would return `null` if there was nothing matching that `id` - for instance, if the code ran *before* the dynamic elements had been created. Fixing the `onload` assignment might help with that.

Comment: That's why I asked. I removed the parenthesis, but still no change. How can I assure that running this code is the last thing that happens?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that as the function name suggests, `getElementsByClassName` returns a list of element**S**, not a single element. If you know the specific element (the div element) you want to modify is the first / only element that will match the criteria, you can access it with `[0]`.
Try:

```
var TooltipElement = document.getElementsByClassName("classname")[0];
```

Also, since your div has an ID, you'd actually be better off with:

```
var TooltipElement = document.getElementById("identifier");
```

Always prefer using an ID when you're targeting a single, specific element. It's is much more concise, accurate and performs better.

See working example:

```js
var TooltipElement = document.getElementById("identifier");
TooltipElement.title = "new title";
```

```html
<div title="tooltip text" class="classname" id="identifier">Some text</div>
```

Comment: I understand your logic, but making this change returns "Unable to set property 'title' of undefined or null reference". Also, I get the same message when I attempt to use getElementById.

Comment: @Phil That doesn't sound right. I've added a snippet to show how that works.

Comment: That's exactly what I have and still once the page loads fully, the original title attribute remains, plus I'm getting the same error as before.

Comment: Then you should post a MCVE (read [ask]). You should be able to see it ***does*** work in the snippet in my answer.